# How do you wait for useAuth useEffect to return the current user state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, router

I have a bit of a problem implementing authentication for my React application. I followed [this](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/auth-workflow) link to get the authentication going. Here's my App component:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <ProvideAuth>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Switch>
          <PrivateRoute exact path="/">
            <Dashboard />
          </PrivateRoute>
          <Route path="/login">
            <Login />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </ProvideAuth>
  );
}

function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  let auth = useAuth();
  console.log("USER: ", auth.user);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        auth.user ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )} />
  )
}

export default App;
```

Login component:

```
const Login = () => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');

    let history = useHistory();
    let location = useLocation();
    let auth = useAuth();

    let { from } = location.state || { from: { pathname: "/" } }
    let login = (e) => {
        auth.signin(email, password, () => {
            history.replace(from);
        });
    };

    return (
        <div>
          <input onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} value={email} type="email" />
          <input onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} value={password} type="password" />
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

Finally use-auth.js:

```
const authContext = createContext();

export function ProvideAuth({ children }) {
    const auth = useProvideAuth();

    return <authContext.Provider value={auth}>{children}</authContext.Provider>;
};

export const useAuth = () => {
    return useContext(authContext);
};

function useProvideAuth() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

    const signin = (email, password, callback) => {
        axios.post(`${apiUrl}/sign_in`, {
            'email': email,
            'password': password
        },
            {
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }

            }).then(res => {
                const expiryDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000).toUTCString();
                document.cookie = `access-token=${res.headers['access-token']}; path=/; expires=${expiryDate}; secure; samesite=lax`;
                return res.data
            })
            .then(data => {
                setUser(data.data);
                callback();
            })
            .catch(e => {
                setUser(null);
            });
    };

    const signout = () => {
        document.cookie = "access-token=; expires = Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
        setUser(null);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const cookies = getCookies();
        if (cookies['access-token']) {
            axios.get(`${apiUrl}/user_info`, {
                headers: {
                    ...cookies
                }
            }).then(res => {
                return res.data;
            })
                .then(data => {
                    setUser(data);
                })
                .catch(e => {
                    setUser(null);
                })
        } else {
            setUser(null);
        }
    }, []);

    return {
        user,
        signin,
        signout
    }
}

function getCookies() {
    let cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
    let authTokens = {
        'access-token': null
    };

    for (const cookie of cookies) {
        let cookiePair = cookie.split('=');

        if (authTokens.hasOwnProperty(cookiePair[0].trim().toLowerCase()))
            authTokens[cookiePair[0].trim()] = decodeURIComponent(cookiePair[1]);
    }

    return authTokens;
}
```

and then the dashboard component is the homepage. Nothing interesting.

The problem is when a user is in fact logged in (the access-token cookie is set as well as other tokens), they're still routed to the login page because of the fact that calling the API which checks that these tokens are valid is asynchronous, so the user is set to null initially.

What am I missing here? how can I wait until the API response is returned without blocking the user interface? Should I save user state in the redux state or is there some other work around?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Add a new state, e.g. "loading", then share that through the context just like you already do with the user. Then do something like `{loading && <Spinner />}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Jonas Wilms suggested, I added a loading state variable in user-auth similar to user and set it to true before each request and false after the request is completed.

In my App component, I changed the PrivateRoute function to show a loading spinner as long as the user state is loading. When it's set to false, I check whether the user is logged in or not and show the Dashboard component or redirect to login page accordingly.

```
function PrivateRoute({ children, ...rest }) {
  let auth = useAuth();
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) =>
        auth.loading ? 
        <Loading /> :
        auth.user ? (
          children
        ) : (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: "/login",
              state: { from: location }
            }}
          />
        )} />
  )
}
```